# Why is my application not being deployed on OpenShift?

Tags: node.js, openshift

I believe I have everything set up properly for my server but I keep getting this error

```
Starting NodeJS cartridge
Tue Jan 05 2016 10:49:19 GMT-0500 (EST): Starting application 'squadstream' ...
Waiting for application port (8080) become available ...
Application 'squadstream' failed to start (port 8080 not available)
-------------------------
Git Post-Receive Result: failure
Activation status: failure
Activation failed for the following gears:
568be5b67628e1805b0000f2 (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to
execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/568be5b67628e1805b0000f2/nodejs
#<IO:0x0000000082d2a0>
#<IO:0x0000000082d228>
)
Deployment completed with status: failure
postreceive failed
```

I have my git repo set up with all the steps followed properly.

https://github.com/ammark47/SquadStreamServer

Edit: I have another app on openshift that is on 8080. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: The thing I'd look into first is where it says "port 8080 not available". You'll likely want to use the port in the environment variable `OPENSHIFT_<cart-name>_PORT` or `. You can use the 'rhc' tool (or common linux tools, if you're ssh'd in) to view this variable. If 8080 is the right value, you might want to double check that the application is properly stopped (and the port therefore freed) before you try starting it again.

Comment: do you know how I can view the variable OPENSHIFT_<cart-name>_PORT ? i have rhc

Comment: Probably `rhc env-list`? See https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-common-rhc-commands.html.

Comment: that doesn't bring up anything

Comment: @Ezra I have another app on openshift that is on 8080. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Re your question on how to list environment variables, you can ssh into your gear (`rhc ssh <yourApp>`) and run `export`. (But the port is correct.) To get more details I recommend sshing into your app and checking the `~/app-root/logs/nodejs.log` for additional details.

Answer (score 0):

If the other application is running on the same gear, then it is binding to port 8080 first, making it unavailable for your second application.  You will need to run each application on it's own gear.  Also, you need to make sure that you are binding to port 8080 on the correct IP address for your gear, you can't bind to 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1